# When using win32 assembly, how do you get the state of a key?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I have the following code where I attempt to print "Hello, World" until the escape key is pressed. But, I ran into an issue. GetKeyState doesn't seem to be retrieving the key. I have two lines, `push 0x27` and `move eax, 0x27` because I am a little confused on how to know whether the dll being called is going to want the parameter pushed to the stack or provided via the register. But, even with providing both, nothing seems to happen.

I ran the program in a debugger and EAX is always returned as 0 whether escape is pressed or not. What am I doing wrong here?

```
global Start
extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ExitProcess@4
extern _GetKeyState@4

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE equ -10
NULL equ 0

section .data
consoleInHandle dd 1

section .bss
buffer2 resd 2

section .text

Start:
    mov esi,0
    ; DWORD bytes;
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 4

    ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

write:
    ; WriteFile ( hstdOut, message, length (message), &bytes, 0);
    add esi,1
    push 0
    lea eax, [ebp-4]
    push eax
    push (message_end - message)
    push message
    push ebx
    call _WriteFile@20
    ;_GetKeyState
    read:
    mov eax, 0x27 ;Tried
    push 0x27     ;Tried
    call _GetKeyState@4
    test eax, 0x8000
    jz write
    exit:
    ;ExitProcess (0)
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
    ; never here
    hlt

message:
    db 'Hello, World', 10
message_end:
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate

Comment: `VK_ESCAPE` is `0x1b`

Comment: @DanielA.White Wow, I need to fix my resources. That solved it. Thank you.

Comment: @VCD_WL: Every time your code is doing the `_WriteFile()`  a user can press and release the escape key; and every time you call `_GetKeyState()` the key may be in a "not pressed" state. In other words (in theory), the user could be frantically hammering the daylights out of their escape key and your code won't know. To avoid this, you either need to use STDIN or a message handler.